# schrodinger or schroedinger tags: please standardize

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

What applies to [Gödel](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/changing-the-godel-tag),<sup>1</sup> may also apply to two Schrödinger tags: [schrodinger-equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schrodinger-equation) and [non-linear-schrodinger](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-linear-schrodinger). The third one, [schroedingers-cat](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schroedingers-cat), being "right" already. So, whatever you may think of the umlaut, as it is now, it is being "translated" inconsistently.

This would be a good use case for a tag synonym. Should we standardize on `oe` or `o`? It probably should be the former, of course, but we could run into an issue with tag length. (I think not.)

Perhaps, after a while, a mod may make a tag synonym and merge the tags into the properly spelled ones.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Ignore the comments over there.</sup>

Comment: We need a (1/sqrt(2))(|Schroedinger> + |Schrödinger>) tag

Comment: Is the umlaut simply not recognized on SE tags? Then it's probably the same for a whole lot of accents: [poincare-symmetry](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poincare-symmetry), [reissner-nordstrom-metric](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reissner-nordstrom-metric).

Comment: @fffred You're not suggesting this, but I'm not asking for the umlaut (which, even if possible, might create problems for autocomplete and some users). I'm (secondarily) asking for `oe` instead of `o`, which is _the_ standard _for German (and Austrian) names_ (even when used by English-writing folk, I'm quite sure) when `ö` is not available or not desired. I do _not_ know how the Finns deal with their `ö`. (And my primary concern is consistency among the Schrödinger-tags.)

Comment: Unicode in tags is something that can be enabled for sites like [japanese.se], etc. It's better left alone sincr tag-autocompletion would get icky. (of course, a bunch of synonyms would nullify that) Also we need to demonstrate that there is a need (one or two transliterable tag names doesn't count). As far as Schr(o[e?]|ö)dinger goes, I've almost always seen the ö replaced with an o. I have seen ö quite a few times, and oe very rarely. Could br a language thing; being an English site it would be better to keep the English transliteration as standard if we can't use ö.

Comment: As an English-writing folk, I agree with Manishearth. I'm only vaguely aware of `ö → oe`, which I suppose gets the pronunciation across better but still looks off. Though I just checked and my American English spellchecker recommends "Schrodinger" be changed to either (1) "Schrödinger" *or* (2) "Schroedinger," where the ordering is probably determined solely by similarity to what I typed. BTW, suggestion (10) is "Schmo dingier," which I suggest be used in the event no other consensus can be reached :P

Answer (score 13):

Let's standardize with `oe`. Vote up if you agree.

Comment: +1 "[I]n limited character sets such as ASCII, O-umlaut [not to be confused with O-diaeresis] is frequently replaced with the digraph "oe". (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D6#O-umlaut).) "_Any_ individual change from "Schrodinger" to "Schroedinger" will be an improvement[.]" (See [Wikipedia Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASchr%F6dinger_equation%2Farchive_1#Old_messages).)

Comment: *"Vote up if you agree"* [Metas already work like that](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences). By giving a higher preference to `Vote-up`, I have a thought that you're expecting me vote up all the answers :D

Comment: As a language student I can't but support this choice. :P

Answer (score -1):

We should push to have `ö` enabled in tags so that we can standardize with that. Vote up if you agree.

Comment: This may not sit well with those whose keyboards don't have umlauts, unless the tag recognition software can consistently and reliably turn `Schrodinger` into `Schrödinger`.

Comment: (I notice that not even [tag:Schrödinger] works!)

Comment: No! We shouldn't have to go to WP to copy paste those weird symbols.

Answer (score -4):

Let's standardize with `o`. Vote up if you agree.

Comment: What? -4? Why do people want oe?

Comment: Because that is the standard way of spelling German ö when you don't have a typewriter with umlauts. In other words, this is the correct way to do it ***for the German language*** and Schroedinger (Schrödinger) is a German name. Would you spell Göthe "Gothe". Would you spell Schönberg "Schonberg".